# Function returns correct value when i use conditional operator or if statement without return statement

Tags: c, function, if-statement, return-value, conditional-operator

```
#include<stdio.h>
int fact(int);
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    printf("enter a number : ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    b=fact(a);
    printf("\n%d",b);
}
int fact(int y )
{
    int d=1;
    for(int i = 1;i<=y;i++)
            d*=i;
    d= d>0 ? d : 0;
}
```

If I remove the last statement , O/P is a+1.
I have checked this with other functions and the function returns correct values if I use if statement or conditional operator.
I want to know why this happens.
Thank You.

Comment: You have not returned any value from the function, so anything that happens is coincidental. It would be better to focus on writing correct code, than to wonder about the result of undefined behaviour.

Comment: If you are curious as to what happened "under the hood" you could single-step the code with a debugger. What happens may be educative, but won't be the same behaviour from machine to machine etc.

Comment: You should be getting a warning from the compiler that you have no `return` statement in the function.

Comment: Oftentimes (but by no means all the time) the same processor register that's used for returning values from functions is also the register that's used for holding intermediate results of calculations.  So if function A calls function B thinking that function B returns a value, but function B doesn't actually contain a `return` statement, what function A fetches from that register (imagining it to be the official return value) will often be something vaguely sensible, like the last number function B worked with. (Obviously you would never want to deliberately depend on such quirks, though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **6.9.1 Function definitions**
> ...
> 12 If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by
> the caller, the behavior is undefined.

Simply put, the behavior you're seeing is purely accidental.  There's no good reason why you should get that particular result or any other.

*Undefined* means that the code is erroneous, but neither the compiler nor the runtime environment are required to handle it in any particular way.  What's likely happening in your case is that the register used to return a value from a function is also being used to store the value of `d`, but that doesn't *have* to be true.  If you change up the code, you may get a different result.